# 'getMonth()' is deprecated

Tags: java, android

Estoy obteniendo el mes actual de la siguiente manera:

```
int mesActual = new Date().getMonth() +1; //enero=0 diciembre=11
```

Pero este método es Obsoleto. ¿Cómo lo reemplazo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La respuesta de @Rene Limon es la solución, podrías omitir el date para escribir menos líneas de código innecesarias quedando así:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int mesActual = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Comment: hola falta +1 °

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() ya devuelve la fecha actual como si fuera el new Date(), por tanto, es una tontería hacer el new Date para después asignarlo al Calendar. Tu respuesta debería ser la válida (salvo que te falta sumarle 1).

Comment: he comentando las 2 lineas y me anda bien

Answer (score 2):

De esta forma:

```
java.util.Date date= new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int mesActual = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
```

Comment: hola falta  +1 °

Comment: corregido, gracias @Elenasys!

Comment: Gracias! todo perfecto

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que obtener el día, mes o año a partir de una instancia de Calendar:

```
//int mesActual = new Date().getMonth() +1;//enero=0 diciembre=11
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        int diaActual = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int mesActual = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        int anioActual = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

---

Importante hacer notar que para obtener el més debes sumar 1, ya que el primer mes es 0, por esta razón se obtiene de esta forma:

```
        int mesActual = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

> [**MONTH**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) : Número de campo para get y set que indica el mes. Este es un valor específico del calendario. El primer mes del año en los
>   calendarios gregoriano y juliano es ENERO que es 0; El último
>   depende del número de meses en un año.